# get cloudfront usage report via aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a bunch of `Cloudfront` distributions scattered across a number of AWS accounts. I'd like to get the **Usage Reports** for *all Cloudfront distros across all AWS accounts*.

Now, I have the change-account bit already automated, but I'm not sure how to get the `CSV` report via the `AWS CLI`.

I know I can do some ClickOps and download the report via [the Cloudfront Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudwatch-csv.html), like here:

[image]

**but I can't find the command to get the report with the AWS CLI.**

I know [I can get the Cloudfront metrics via the Cloudwatch API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/programming-cloudwatch-metrics.html) but the documentation doesn't mention the API endpoint I should be querying.

Also, there's [aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html), but I'm not sure how to use that to download the `Cloudfront Usage CSV Report`.

---

**Question**: *How can I get the Cloudfront Usage Report for all distributions in an AWS account using the AWS CLI?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't find a Cloudfront API to fetch the Usage Report. I know such report can be constructed from Cloudwatch logs, but I'm lazy and I'd like to download the report directly from Cloudfront.

There is no such command in AWS CLI or function in Boto3 (AWS SDK for Python) introduced yet but there are a couple of workarounds that you can use which are as follows:

1. Use Selenium to access AWS Console for CloudFront and click on that `Download CSV` button. You can write a script for that in Python.
2. You can use the curl command used by CloudFront on AWS Console to fetch the results in XML format and then you can convert them into CSV using Python or any CLI tool. That curl command can be found after clicking on the `Download CSV` button and then from the item named `cloudfrontreporting` which appears under the `Network` tab under `Inspect` console on the page in `Google Chrome` browser (or using any other browser of your choice), right-click on that item and then click on `Copy as cURL` button.

The curl command is as follows:

```
curl 'https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/v3/api/cloudfrontreporting' \
  -H 'authority: console.aws.amazon.com' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'x-csrf-token: ${CSRF_TOKEN}' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'origin: https://console.aws.amazon.com' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/v3/home?region=eu-central-1' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cookie: ${COOKIE}' \
  --data-raw '{"headers":{"X-Amz-User-Agent":"aws-sdk-js/2.849.0 promise"},"path":"/2014-01-01/reports/series","method":"POST","region":"us-east-1","params":{},"contentString":"<DataPointSeriesRequestFilters xmlns=\"http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2014-01-01/\"><Report>Usage</Report><StartTime>2022-01-28T11:23:35Z</StartTime><EndTime>2022-02-04T11:23:35Z</EndTime><TimeBucketSizeMinutes>ONE_DAY</TimeBucketSizeMinutes><ResourceId>All Web Distributions (excludes deleted)</ResourceId><Region>ALL</Region><Series><DataKey><Name>HTTP</Name><Description></Description></DataKey><DataKey><Name>HTTPS</Name><Description></Description></DataKey><DataKey><Name>HTTP-BYTES</Name><Description></Description></DataKey><DataKey><Name>HTTPS-BYTES</Name><Description></Description></DataKey><DataKey><Name>BYTES-OUT</Name><Description></Description></DataKey><DataKey><Name>BYTES-IN</Name><Description></Description></DataKey><DataKey><Name>FLE</Name><Description></Description></DataKey></Series></DataPointSeriesRequestFilters>","operation":"listDataPointSeries"}' \
  --compressed > report.xml
```

where `${CSRF_TOKEN}` and `${COOKIE}` needs to be provided by yourself which can be found from the browser or can be prepared programmatically.

3. Use logs generated by CloudFront as mentioned here in the answer and code in the question: [Boto3 CloudFront Object Usage Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64017728/boto3-cloudfront-object-usage-count)

Comment: This is looking really good! What would be your suggestion to automate the token and cookie substitution?

Comment: @baduker, I would suggest going with the solution based on Selenium in Python because for that you just need to configure the AWS access keys or maybe login before running it, and no need to configure even the AWS access keys. For curl, you need to figure out a way to create those 2 secrets (`${CSRF_TOKEN}` and `${COOKIE}`). You may use `urllib2` to curl the AWS console to get those or maybe prepare by yourself but you still need to login to the AWS console before doing so as those get expired after the login session gets expired.

Comment: @baduker, Not only that, if you look at the actual values for those 2 secrets when you get it from the browser console, you will realize that it is not easy to prepare the value for `${COOKIE}`. Maybe there might be some AWS CLI commands or Boto3 APIs which you can use to prepare those values but not sure.

Comment: @baduker, I think you can use the following API for a token but not sure about cookie: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-session-token.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Cost-Explorer API for that.

```
aws ce get-cost-and-usage \                                                                                                        
--time-period Start=2022-01-01,End=2022-01-03 \
--granularity MONTHLY \
--metrics "BlendedCost" "UnblendedCost" "UsageQuantity" \
--group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=SERVICE Type=TAG,Key=Environment
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/get-cost-and-usage.html#examples